# Brute force method on Caesar cipher not working for me

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

The output of this code is:

The original encrypted text then a list of numbers up to 26

I don't know why this happens, could you please help me?

P.S.: The deciphered text is "arrive a dawn"

I'm sorry if this is a bad question this is the first time I've done this.

```
MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

file1 = open(r"encryped.txt", "r")

before = file1.read

key = 0
def gettranslatedmessage(key, before):

    translated = ''

    for symbol in before():

        if symbol.isalpha():
          num = ord(symbol)
          num += key

          if symbol.isupper():
                    if num > ord('Z'):
                        num -= 26

                    elif num < ord('A'):

                        num += 26
          elif symbol.islower():
            if num > ord('z'):
             num -= 26
            elif num < ord('a'):
             num+= 26

          translated += chr(num)
        else:
          translated += symbol
    return translated 


for key in range(1, MAX_KEY_SIZE + 1):
   print(key, gettranslatedmessage(key, before))

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of the loop you read the entire file. You translate it with `key == 1` and print that translation.

On all the remaining iterations, there's nothing left in the file to read, so `before()` returns an empty string and `for symbol in before():` doesn't do anything. That call to `gettranslatedmessage()` returns an empty `translated` string, and `print(key, gettranslatedmessage(key, before))` prints the key followed by that empty string.

You should read the file once into a string, and pass that string to the function instead of passing the function. Change the assignment to:

```
before = file1.read()
```

and change the loop to:

```
for symbol in before:
```

Comment: Hi @mrhodgehag . Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider clicking the "accept" button if you think this is the right answer.